# Unresponsive Keyboard and Trackpad after sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos, magic-trackpad

I have a brand new MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014). Shipped with Yosemitee pre-installed, the version I have is 10.10.1 . I don't have any software installed except Google Chrome, so it is clean/new OS.

I noticed sometimes the keyboard and trackpad become completely unresponsive after waking up the laptop from sleep. Happened several times, the last time it happened I could not reset PRAM or SMC as keyboard was unresponsive even after restarting or shutting down so I had to Re-Install OS.

Today I was able to reproduce the issue, first I tried to let it go into Sleep mode several times with no device plugged into the USBs, and Lid left opened. I could not reproduce, both were working when I wake the laptop.

Then I plugged in a USB Mouse, left the lid opened, and let it go to sleep for 1 hr. When I waked it up, the keyboard/mouse were unresponsive. Then I unplugged the mouse usb, let it go into sleep mode, and closed the lid .. for few minutes. Then I opened the lid, waked it up .. this time both were responsive and working.

I was able to reproduce the above scenarios, so it is not a random thing.

So, is there some kind of a log or test I can use to reproduce or while reproducing the unresponsive case above so I can understand if it is a hardware or software problem ?

[edit]

You can get the system.log from here 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3x320cieum3it4w/system.log?dl=0

Also, here is the result of 'pmset -g'

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1*
AC Power        -1
Currently in use:
standbydelay         10800
standby              1
halfdim              1
hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
darkwakes            0
gpuswitch            2
disksleep            0
sleep                1
autopoweroffdelay    14400
hibernatemode        3
autopoweroff         1
ttyskeepawake        1
displaysleep         2
acwake               0
lidwake              1
```

[edit 2]
Sorry I undo the selected solution as it did not fix the issue, as I have new information, they are unresponsive again and this time I see this keeps showing in the system log, any idea ?

```
Dec 12 23:49:30 ahmads-mbp kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002c0 (interface 1, reportID 0xd9)
Dec 12 23:49:30 ahmads-mbp kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
Dec 12 23:49:31 ahmads-mbp kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_getFeatureReportInfo - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002c0 (interface 1, reportID 0xd1)
Dec 12 23:49:31 ahmads-mbp kernel[0]: AppleUSBMultitouchDebug: _getFeatureReportInfo returned an error in AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReportWithLookUp
```

[edit 3]

I managed to downgrade it to Mavericks but problem still happening. I think it is hardware issue now since I was able to reproduce in two OS X versions. So I am taking it to apple store to replace it or fix the hardware.

[Edit 4]
Confirmed! it is a hardware issue, I replaced the top case and the problem gone!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Good first question, well researched.

Comment: You could add information on your pmset -g and your console report from the time you wake up the computer.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I updated the question to include the pmset output, and I included system.log report, is this the correct report file ?

Comment: Great! reading it!, so you use a USB hub ?

Comment: Madrid Spain- was there, I love that city. So while I am looking for the USB problem you could fix another one by following the instructions here http://ispire.me/fix-yosemite-rtc-alarm-wakeup-issue/

Comment: @Buscar웃 I don't use a USB hub, I have an external usb keyboard with multiple ends, may be you are referring to that ? Thanks for the link I will look into it :)

Comment: It is none of my business but why are you with zte.com.cn ?

Comment: it turns out the zte.com.cn came from the ADSL modem I use to connect to the internet. :)

Comment: I have a similar issue so I guess it might be also hardware related..    `Nov  3 09:21:07 MBPMarssStefano kernel[0] <Notice>: USBF:    60950.530    IOUSBHIDDriver(AppleUSBMultitouchDriver)::RearmInterruptRead  returning error 0xe00002c0 (no such device), not issuing any reads to device
Nov  3 09:21:07 MBPMarssStefano kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::_deviceGetReport - DeviceRequest returned error 0xe00002d8 (interface 0, reportID 0x0)
Nov  3 09:21:07 MBPMarssStefano kernel[0] <Notice>: AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::handleSuspend - SuspendPort returned error 0xe00002e2.`

Answer (score 4):

As for me, I, too, faced the same problem with my MacBookPro after upgrading to Yosemite: the keyboard and trackpad would freeze, especially after waking up from sleep. At first, I'd restart the device. 
A few days ago, out of sheer frustration, as I clicked on random keys and rubbed the trackpad, the keyboard and simultaneously, the trackpad, became responsive, quite to my surprise. After several more tries, it now seems to me the key 'Q' was the key- pressing it several times, along with the 'esc'. I don't know how, but this works on my MBPro.
Of course I'm no techie, and have no explanation, but would request interested and affected users to try my approach.

Comment: Bizarre, but works like a charm. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

Analyzing your Console log I came up with:

you have dozens of different problems:

```
RTC (Alarm)
```

Follow the instruction here to fix that.

[**Fix Yosemite rtc alarm wakeup issue**](http://ispire.me/fix-yosemite-rtc-alarm-wakeup-issue/)

Then you have the remote sharing and Management Enabled- I assume you know about that.

You can see that here:

From Ahmads-MacBook-Pro

to

Dec  6 19:47:32 ahmads-mbp.zte.com.cn configd[25]: setting hostname to "ahmads-mbp.zte.com.cn"

Are you using a `zte.com.cn` device ?

Still did not find what is going on with the USB, but would recommended:

1- Disable any and all sharing to test.

2- Run permissions repair in Disk Utility.

Comment: Interesting .. I don't use any device from zte.com.cn, I don't know where that name came from. may be a virus ? :)

Comment: As for remote management and sharing, it is not enabled, disabled in my both laptops. I have two Macbook pros connected to same network, would it be one of them remotely trying to wake up the other via network ?

Comment: Also I am not sure if this information is important but I would like to share it. Old macbook name is "Ahmad's MacBook Pro" and the new one is "Ahmad's MacBook Pro (2)". Old macbook name in network is "Ahmads-MacBook-Pro-2.local" and the new one is "Ahmads-MacBook-Pro.local" but I doubt it has anything to do with this bug.

Comment: I have not  tried the rct alarm wakeup fix solution yet. Right now whenever I try to leave my laptop i un-plug everything :) now I have another problem where kernal_test goes banana and consume cpu usages +500. This OS is useless and as a coder I cannot do any useful thing on it, and I cannot downgrade to Mavericks as this machine is pre-installed with Yosemite -_- Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually your computer is in trouble. I would recommend you do the cmd-r and reinstall Yosemite. If you want you can go back to Mavericks but that is another story.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! Should I start new question about downgrading to Mavericks ? I have searched online and most of them are saying you cannot downgrade because the machine comes with Yoesmite pre-installed.

Comment: For now just restore the Yosemite and see if it works. As I said you have lots of stuff going on that should not be. Yes getting Mavericks could be tricky, for example you would have to wipe the hard drive and have Mavericks Installer (not available online).

Comment: I have reinstalled Yosemite 2 times in the past 10 days, I purchased it 14 days ago :) the unresponsive issue will keep happening, and the kernal_test issue started to happen after I started installing softwares, so probably i will end up with same problem after re-installing :S I have mavericks installed into a hard disk (external) but when I tried to install it it declined stating that it is old version.

Comment: sorry to hear, try the standard repairs as in my answer, restore the permissions, remove suspicious software (look in Activity monitor), Log in as new user, etc..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19291/discussion-between-ahmad-alkhawaja-and-buscar).